# How To send SQL or any text file from Localhost to a Website using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have and SQL file on my Local machine and i want to send this file to my another localhost machine which is acting like my Websites. After that i want to execute this file and update the database of my Website . I tried it using CURL but doesn't work as expected.My sender and receiver files are given below and i have two more file Sql_generator.php and sql_execute.php(Which is executing the sql file that is recieved at server side ). Please tell me where i am doing it wrong because i run this demo on single localhost machine where code is working fine but when i use it from one machine to another then empty sql file is generated at server side. Please Help !!

**Sender.php**

```
<?php
     include('sqlGenerator.php');
     include('connect.php');
     if(isset($_POST['sendfile'])){
       // Creating a Back Up from Client-Side-Database
       $return = backup_tables($name);
      if($return){
      echo "</br> <b>Back Up!! </b>is created successfully.  </br></br>";

    //clean your post here  
    $path = $_POST['db_file'];      
    $post = "file_address=".$path;
    //Where are you sending it to?
    $url = "http://192.168.1.21/final2/filereceiver.php";

    //echo $post;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);     
    curl_close($ch);    

    if($response){
        echo "</br> <b>Congratulation!! </b> Your File has been Send Successfully </br></br>";
        echo $response;     
    }
     else{ echo "File not sent"; }
   }
} ?>

<form action="sendfile.php" method="post"/>
    <input type="file" name="db_file" value="http://192.168.1.20/xampp/htdocs/final/db.sql" readOnly="true"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sendfile" value="Send File To Server"/>
</form>
```

**Receiver.php**

```
<?php 
      include("execute_sql.php");
      class Download extends Executer{
         const URL_MAX_LENGTH = 2050;
         //clean url
         protected function cleanUrl($url){
         if(isset($url)){
         if(!empty($url)){
            if(strlen($url) < self::URL_MAX_LENGTH){
                return strip_tags($url);
            }
        }
    }
}

//is url
protected function isUrl($url){
    $url = $this->cleanUrl($url);
    if(isset($url)){
        if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)){
            return $url;
        }
    }
}

// return extension 
protected function returnExtension ($url){
    if($this->isUrl($url)){
        $end = end(preg_split("/[.]/", $url));
        if(isset($end)){
            return $end;
        }
    }
}

//Download file
public function downloadFile($url){
    if($this->isUrl($url)){
        $extension = $this->returnExtension($url);
        if($extension){
            // curl Session
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $serverside_filename = "server_database_file";
            $destination = "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/downloads/$serverside_filename.$extension";


            $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
            fputs($file, $return);
            if(fclose($file)){                  
                if(file_exists($destination)){
                    echo "<b>Server Says :- </b>Localhost send me a file successfully.. </br>
                    File is available at :-  {$destination}</br></br>";
                }
                $path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/downloads/server_database_file.sql";
                $obj1 = new Executer();
                $res = $obj1->execute($path);
                if($res){
                    echo "Your Data is inserted in Server's Database Successfully</br></br>";                       
                }
                else{
                    echo "Your Data Insertion is still Pending........</br> ";
                }

            }
        }
    }
} } ?>

<?php $obj = new Download();
  if(isset($_POST['url'])){
    $url = $_POST['url'];
  } 
// Receiving the file address from sender
if(isset($_POST['file_address'])){  
    $url = $_POST['file_address'];
    if(isset($url)){
        $obj->downloadFile($url);
    }

}
else{ 
    echo "</br>Sorry your file is not received";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you are "sending" to the server isn't sent as a plain php file. It is actually getting processed by the webserver on your machine as the server requests it.

You need to modify the curl request to actually send the php file rather than a link to it.

A quick Google search gave me this article which might be useful:

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/